# parameter passing while generating report in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, report

I have attached a figure. I know how to generate report in ASP.NET. Please suggest me how to pass parameter while generating report exactly as shown in the figure.
[image]

Is there any video related to this

Comment: Show us some of your code? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i am not getting how to pass parameter in report itself

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SSRS ReportViewer control. You have 2 options:

1. If you're using default SSRS ReportViewer.aspx you can pass
   parameter through the URL, like that:

   http:///ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?PathToReport&rs:Command=Render&ExamYear=2013
2. If you're using ReportViewer control directly, pass parameter in the
   codebehind:

   ReportParameter examYearParam = new ReportParameter("ExamYear", 2013);
   reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(examYearParam);